# Does MonoTouch support NSInvocationOperation yet?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I've googl'd about, looking for an monotouch example using NSInvocationOperation, no luck.
I also can't find the class in the touch framework library. (Only the NSOperation class.)

Now, I can use threading to load info asynchronously, however I'm thinking that the iPhone operation stack might be the preferred method.

Is NSInvocationOperation not supported yet?

Answer (score 1):

No it does not, as you should use the threadpool, and QueueUserWorkItem and friends.

Comment: Understood. Threading it is then. However the ThreadingPool model feels a little lacking in functionality. I don't think you can cancel an item waiting to be executed. The NSInvocationOperation stuff looked sweeter. I'll probably write my own queuing library to handle the funny stuff.